# What is Redis error : getaddrinfo NOT FOUND redis or other error?

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose, redis

"Re-viewing". But on the server, I get the error:

`276.6 [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo NOT FOUND redis 0 276.6 in GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)` .

or

```
Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
#0 248.8     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
```

The error "getaddrinfo NOT FOUND redis" indicates that the ioredis library cannot resolve the hostname "redis" to an IP address. This can happen if the DNS record for the "redis" host is not configured or is not available. The radish itself when running the command : redis-cli the response is correct 127.0.0.1:6379 and in response to redis-cli ping I get a PONG response, but when I try to bring down the project on the server after running docker compose I get an error ( Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo NOT FOUND redis 0 276.6 in GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) ) . Perhaps there is a mistake in my docker's offices or in env, I no longer understand what else could be wrong there...
My configuration is Next.js  Prisma database, server with Node

My docker-compose:

```
#app arkont
  app-arkont:
    container_name: app-arkont
    image: arkont-image
    build:
      context: arkont
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379 
    networks:
      - arkont-net
    env_file: 
      - arkont/.env
    ports:
      - 7000:3000
    depends_on:
      - "db-arkont"
    command: sh -c "sleep 13 && npx prisma migrate deploy && npm start"
    links:
      - redis:redis   
  
  # Redis
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always\
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - arkont-net
      
  db-arkont:
    container_name: db-arkont
    env_file:
      - arkont/.env
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-arkont-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - arkont-net

 #adminer 
  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    networks:
      - arkont-net

volumes:
  db-arkont-data: {}

networks:
  arkont-net:
    name: arkont-net
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS builder

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/prisma ./prisma

# Install Redis
RUN apk add --update redis

# Copy Redis configuration file
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf  

# Set ownership and permissions for Redis configuration file
RUN chown redis:redis /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

# Set Redis configuration
ENV REDIS_HOST=redis
ENV REDIS_PORT=6379

ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 3000
```

Redis in ENV

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Redis in index.tsx for getStaticProps:

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';

const redisClient = new Redis({
  port: 6379,
  host: 'redis'
});

const getDataFromRedis = (key: string): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //@ts-ignore
    redisClient.get(key, (err: Error | null, data: any) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });

const Home: NextPage<{ cars: AllCarDto, carsUsed: AllUsedCarDto }> = ({ cars, carsUsed }) => { )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  let cars: CarDtoWithoutFavorite[] = []; 
  let carsUsed: AllUsedCarDto = [];
  try {
    const carsData: string = await getDataFromRedis('cars');
    const carsUsedData: string = await getDataFromRedis('carsUsed');

    if (!carsData) {
      cars = await db.car.findMany(
        {
          where: {
            active: true,
          },
          include: {
            CarModel: true,
            CarComplectation: true,
            CarModification: true,
            extras: true,
            DealerModel: true,
          },
        }
      );
      // Redis
      redisClient.set('cars', JSON.stringify(cars));
    } else {
      cars = JSON.parse(carsData) as CarDtoWithoutFavorite[]; /
    }

    if (!carsUsedData) {
      carsUsed = await db.usedCars.findMany({
        where: {
          active: true,
        },
      });
      redisClient.set('carsUsed', JSON.stringify(carsUsed)),
      (err, reply) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error Redis:', err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('success в Redis:', reply);
      }
    } else {
      carsUsed = JSON.parse(carsUsedData) as AllUsedCarDto; 
    }
    // Устанавливаем заголовки Cache-Control и ETag
    context.res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=14400'); 
    context.res.setHeader('ETag', 'some-unique-value'); 
    return {
      props: {
        cars,
        carsUsed,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error querying the database:', error);
    return {
      props: {
        cars: [],
        carsUsed: [],
      },
    };
  }
};
```

I tried changing REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 everywhere, but it didn't help either

Redis answer on server
[image]

[image]

[image]